# Verify that specific joins are made everywhere in a query

Tags: sql-server

I have to go through hundreds of queries in the form of stored procedures and verify that for every join being made that:

1. a specific column join is always made in the join
2. that the join doesn't exist in a hardcoded format to the previous only value of the column (i.e it needs to be like a.requiredJoinColumn = b.requiredJoinColumn and not a.requiredJoinColumn = 'onlyValue'

For example if the required column was named 'reqCol' I'd want to find this as a problem:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
JOIN table b ON a.OtherColumn = b.OtherColumn
```

also,

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
JOIN table b ON a.reqCol = b.reqCol
JOIN table c ON a.OtherColumn = c.otherColumn
```

also, I'd want this to not show up as a problem

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
JOIN table b ON a.reqCol = b.correctColButDifferentName
```

I'd also need it to work on explicitly stated inner and outer joins as well and also in cases where the joins are done via commas (i.e select * from tableA, tableB where a.OtherColumn = b.OtherColumn)

Right now I'm going about this manually and it's taking forever so I was hoping there might be a tool that I could use. Maybe something I could write some validation logic into or with and execute across a series of stored procedures in my SQL Server database.

Comment: There really isn't going to be a way to automate this. There are just way many possibilities. Any kind of automated tool or query would likely return many false positives and at the same miss several violators.

Comment: If I wind up writing this I'd probably start by having query, table, join and column variables and when the query is analyzed, I'd navigate through the list of joins to make sure that one of the join columns per table references my desired column. I know that there's probably some cases (like inner selects) where this isn't necessarily easy, but in my few simple examples I think it'd be pretty easy to find those scenarios properly. Would you agree that for these simple scenarios it shouldn't be a problem or do you see differently?

Comment: Even simple examples this would be nearly impossible. Consider if the aliases are different, the order of columns are different or there are multiple join predicates. And what about "the list of joins". Those could be cross, left, right, outer, implied cross join. How do you define the tables involved just from a query. And what about synonyms? Or remote tables on a linked server. You could spend the next two years writing a tool for this and still miss even "simple" ones. What about table valued functions? The list goes on and on.

Comment: Well SSMS knows what's a table and what isn't, right? It also knows whats a column vs a comment. It understands synonyms and knows the difference between cross and explicit joins and really, all that stuff. I guess you're right in that I don't want to write ssms but I was hoping that there might be a framework or extension or something for VS or SQL or whatever that could give me the information that SSMS already knows. The only thing I think you have right is the column names being different. That'd require some configuration on my part.

Comment: You are talking about queries right? That means it is either a stored procedure, view or function. Or maybe pass through sql. Let's keep it simple and just use a stored procedure. How are you going to find all the tables that are joined in that procedure? You can look at sys.sysdepends as great starting location. But then what? You will have to parse through the text of the procedure looking for your rules. That is where it starts to become absurdly difficult. The point is that you will find some, but it is too complicated to find them all.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wanting. I'm wondering if there's a tool that parses the scripts text similar to how SSMS parses it in order to split the query into it's attributes. If there was then I could write logic on the attributes to look for what ever I'm wanting. It doesn't need to be in SSMS, I'm just wondering if something exists that can do this. Maybe something through Visual Studio. I know it's possible because that's how code parsing works, I just don' know if a parser exists that I can use to write logic on.

Comment: It is done with the sql engine parser. There isn't anything like that short of writing your own parser. Even so you are trying to add additional rules into the mix which are above and beyond query parsing. Maybe somebody knows of a magical tool but I think this is an exercise in futility.

Comment: Even if you do find/write a tool to parse all the SQL in the way that you want - it won't be able to retrieve the SQL for encrypted objects. You'll have to go to your source code control system for that. And if you're using SCC then why wouldn't you start from that in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by encrypted objects but you'd handle it on a per script method. As long as a single script passes then that's all that matters. If the script's results are used in another query then the join to the initial script would need to have the proper join realized. So as far as the encrypted object, I'd say you'd just run it on the script associated w/ that object.

Answer (score 1):

You could "export" the sql_modules and feed them to a sql parser or you could bring a parser in sql server and handle them internally (a bit unorthodox but "creative" at the same time).

There is an [smo parser in .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.parser) and it could be used in a clr module (eg. a scalar function)

```
//r: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser;
using System.Reflection;


namespace sqlns
{
    public partial class SQLParser
    {
        [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None)]
        [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
        public static string SQLParseToXml(string sqlquery)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlquery))
            {
                return sqlquery;
            }

            ParseResult pres = Parser.Parse(sqlquery);
            Object script = pres.GetType().GetProperty("Script", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(pres, null);
            String xmlstr = script.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("Xml").GetValue(script, null).ToString();
            return xmlstr;
        }
    }
}
```

Build the dll and copy to the build location the following two dlls:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.dll

create the assembly & the clr function:

```
create assembly sqlparse from 'C:\path to the project\bin\Debug\xyz.dll'
with permission_set = unsafe;
go

create function dbo.parseSqlToXml(@sql nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max)
with execute as caller, returns null on null input
as
external name [sqlparse].[sqlns.SQLParser].SQLParseToXml;
```

You will have to go through the parser's xml structure and find a way through it to get what you need.

For a  kick-start (and inspiration):

```
select src.modulename,  
    t.col.value('../comment()[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') as joincondition,
    replace(left(t.col.value('(..//*/@Location)[1]', 'varchar(20)'), charindex(',', t.col.value('(..//*/@Location)[1]', 'varchar(20)'))), '(', '') as linenumber, 
    t.col.value('./comment()[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') as columncondition,
    t.col.value('(./SqlScalarRefExpression[1]/@ColumnOrPropertyName)[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as leftcol,
    t.col.value('(./SqlScalarRefExpression[2]/@ColumnOrPropertyName)[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as rightcol,
    t.col.value('(./SqlLiteralExpression[1]/@Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as literal
from 
(
    select object_name(object_id) as modulename, cast(dbo.parseSqlToXml(definition) as xml) as definitionxml
    from sys.sql_modules
) as src
cross apply src.definitionxml.nodes('//SqlQualifiedJoinTableExpression/SqlConditionClause//SqlComparisonBooleanExpression') as t(col);
```

The above, will produce a result set similar to the following (excerpt for modules in msdb)

```
| modulename                                     | joincondition                                                             | linenumber | columncondition                                 | leftcol              | rightcol      | literal                              |
|------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------|-------------------------------------------------|----------------------|---------------|--------------------------------------|
| syscollector_execution_log_full                | (p.id = t.package_id AND p.id != N'84CEC861-D619-433D-86FB-0BB851AF454A') | 25,        | p.id != N'84CEC861-D619-433D-86FB-0BB851AF454A' | id                   | NULL          | 84CEC861-D619-433D-86FB-0BB851AF454A |
| sp_syscollector_delete_execution_log_tree      | ON (node.log_id = leaf.parent_log_id)                                     | 25,        | (node.log_id = leaf.parent_log_id)              | log_id               | parent_log_id | NULL                                 |
| sp_syscollector_delete_execution_log_tree      | ON (l.package_execution_id = s.executionid)                               | 34,        | (l.package_execution_id = s.executionid)        | package_execution_id | executionid   | NULL                                 |
| sp_syscollector_delete_execution_log_tree      | ON i.log_id = l.log_id                                                    | 35,        | i.log_id = l.log_id                             | log_id               | log_id        | NULL                                 |
| sp_syscollector_delete_execution_log_tree      | ON i.log_id = l.log_id                                                    | 40,        | i.log_id = l.log_id                             | log_id               | log_id        | NULL                                 |
| sp_syscollector_delete_collection_set_internal | ON (cs.schedule_uid = sv.schedule_uid)                                    | 29,        | (cs.schedule_uid = sv.schedule_uid)             | schedule_uid         | schedule_uid  | NULL                                 |
| sysutility_mi_configuration                    | ON 1=1                                                                    | 11,        | 1=1                                             | NULL                 | NULL          | 1                                    |
```