# Locating old style joins in existing procedures

Tags: sql-server

I'm migrating and refactoring twenty-something databases to 2019.  All of them contain at least some some stored procedures that use the old, non ANSI joins.  There are over 4,800 procedures total, so I don't want to go through them manually looking for old style joins.  As an added complication, many of the old joins are embedded in dynamic sql, which the SQL Upgrade Advisor doesn't catch.

I'm thinking there must be a way to query sys.sql_modules to identify them, but can't think of what to write for a condition on the definition column.  Can anyone offer suggestions for the ??? below, or offer a different approach?

````
```
SELECT 
    objects.object_id
,   schemas.name AS [Schema]
,   objects.name AS Object_Name
,   objects.type_desc AS [Type]
,   sql_modules.definition AS Definition
FROM 
    sys.sql_modules sql_modules
INNER JOIN sys.objects objects 
    ON sql_modules.object_id = objects.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas schemas 
    ON objects.schema_id = schemas.schema_id 
WHERE 
    sql_modules.definition COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%??????????????????%' ESCAPE '\' 
AND objects.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE';
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will be possible to implicitly identify non-ANSI stored procedures via interrogating the definition alone, but you can certainly narrow down the number you have to look at. I just tested this on a database that has around 430 stored procedures, where I know there are no non-ANSI joins. It came up with 40 false positives. Certainly better than looking through all 430:

```
SELECT 
    objects.object_id
,   schemas.name AS [Schema]
,   objects.name AS Object_Name
,   objects.type_desc AS [Type]
,   sql_modules.definition AS Definition
FROM 
    sys.sql_modules sql_modules
INNER JOIN sys.objects objects 
    ON sql_modules.object_id = objects.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas schemas 
    ON objects.schema_id = schemas.schema_id 

-- Pick up only those statements that have 'FROM' in the definition
WHERE sql_modules.definition COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%FROM%'

-- Exclude any statements that have 'JOIN' in the definition
AND sql_modules.definition COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT LIKE '%JOIN%'

-- Exclude any where there is no comma found after the FROM statement
AND CHARINDEX(
    ',',
    SUBSTRING(
        sql_modules.definition,
        CHARINDEX(
            'FROM',
            sql_modules.definition
        ),
        LEN(sql_modules.definition)
    )
) > 0

AND objects.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE';
```

Comment: Most of the procedures are insert into a temp table or table variable before doing multiple update statements, so almost all have commas after a FROM.  I've also found a couple so far that use ANSI joins in the non-dynamic part of the SQL, but have old joins in the dynamic parts (because of course there are).



I've been trying to avoid it, but I'm fearing I may need to check for a
FROM followed by a comma, unless finding an UPDATE, ORDER, GROUP, or SELECT.   That'll require some sort of while not done type loop because some of these statements have 10+ FROM clauses in them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply though.  I added that to and edit, but too late :)

Gotta love legacy apps from 2003.

Comment: I don't really have an answer then, it sounds like a quite painful decommission job. Good luck with it. I'll leave the answer here in case it benefits any searchers in future.

Answer (score 0):

using a [clr parser function, dbo.parseSqlToXml()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196318/verify-that-specific-joins-are-made-everywhere-in-a-query/60218548#60218548)

--a dummy proc, for testing

```
create procedure testxyz
as
begin

exec('
select *
from tableA as a, tableB as b
where a.id = b.columnid
')


exec('
select *
from X as x
join Y as y on x.col1 = y.col2
where x.id = y.columnid
')


exec('
select *
from (select * from X) as x
join (select * from Y) as y on x.col1 = y.col2
where x.id = y.columnid
')

exec('
select *
from (select * from a, b where a.foo = b.bar) as x
join (select * from Y) as y on x.col1 = y.col2
where x.id = y.columnid
');

select *
from (select * from a, b where a.foo = b.bar) as x
join (select * from Y) as y on x.col1 = y.col2
where x.id = y.columnid;

exec sp_executesql N'select * from k, l where k.foo = l.bar '

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'select * from o,p where o.id = p.id';
exec sp_executesql @sql


declare @sql1 nvarchar(max) = N'select * from r,s where r.id = s.id';
exec(@sql1)



--constructed dynamic sql ....
declare @sql2 nvarchar(max) = N'select * from ';
select @sql2 = @sql2 + 'pr,qr where pr.id = qr.id';
exec(@sql2)


update tableX
set col1 = 123
from tableX, TableY
where TableX.id = TableY.id

delete a
from tableAB as a, tableCD as b
where a.id = b.id

insert into #temp(x, y, z)
select a, b, c
from tableX, tableY
where idX=idY


end
```

....the following...

```
--slow...better execute this per proc, or for iterate through batches of procs/modules
select top (50)
    object_name(m.object_id) as modulename,
    sfc.f.value('data((./../../*[local-name() = ("SqlQuerySpecification", "SqlUpdateSpecification", "SqlDeleteSpecification")]/comment())[1])', 'nvarchar(max)') as thequery,
    sfc.f.query('data(comment()[1])') as fromclause,
    stmt.isdynamicsql
from sys.all_sql_modules as m
cross apply (select cast(dbo.parseSqlToXml(m.definition) as xml) as sqlparse) as prs
cross apply
(
    --normal sql
    select prs.sqlparse as thesql, 0 as isdynamicsql
    union all
    select 
    --dynamic (exec/sp_executesql) sql in token_string
    cast(dbo.parseSqlToXml(stuff(reverse(stuff(reverse(replace(replace('xN'+rtrim(ltrim(replace(replace(t.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), '\r\n', ' '), '\t', ' '))), 'xNN', 'xN'), 'XN', '')), 1, 1, '')), 1, 1, '')) as xml) as thesql, 1 as isdynamicsql
    from prs.sqlparse.nodes('SqlScript/SqlBatch/Tokens/Token[@type="TOKEN_STRING"][contains(lower-case(.), "from")]') as t(s)
) as stmt
--..each fromclause in thesql
cross apply stmt.thesql.nodes('//SqlFromClause[count(SqlDerivedTableExpression) + count(SqlTableRefExpression) > 1]') as sfc(f)
order by m.object_id desc;
```

...returns:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------------+
| modulename               | thequery                          | fromclause                               | isdynamicsql |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------------+
| testxyz                  | select * from a, b where a.foo... | from a, b                                | 0            |
| testxyz                  | update tableX set col1 = 123 f... | from tableX, TableY                      | 0            |
| testxyz                  | delete a from tableAB as a, ta... | from tableAB as a, tableCD as b          | 0            |
| testxyz                  | select a, b, c from tableX, ta... | from tableX, tableY                      | 0            |
| testxyz                  | select * from tableA as a, tab... | from tableA as a, tableB as b            | 1            |
| testxyz                  | select * from a, b where a.foo... | from a, b                                | 1            |
| testxyz                  | select * from k, l where k.foo... | from k, l                                | 1            |
| testxyz                  | select * from o,p where o.id =... | from o,p                                 | 1            |
| testxyz                  | select * from r,s where r.id =... | from r,s                                 | 1            |
| sp_MShelpfulltextscript  | select @catname = f.name from ... | from dbo.sysfulltextcatalogs f, dbo.syso | 0            |
| sp_MSgetalternaterecgens | select distinct p.pubid as alt... | from dbo.sysmergesubscriptions s, dbo.sy | 0            |
| sp_check_sync_trigger    | select @trigid = so1.object_id... | from sys.objects so1, sys.objects so2    | 0            |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Not all constructed sql is "parsed" properly.

Alternatively, extended events could capture deprecated features.